# Which commit in plutus repo should we use for Pioneer Program cohort 3?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

As per title, I'm in cohort 3 and trying to follow instructions here:
https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html

When trying to build the playground, i get the following error:
error: attribute 'plutus-playground' in selection path 'plutus-playground.client' not found

It looks like the playground folders have been moved? There is nothing to compile at HEAD, should I be checking out a previous commit for this cohort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas Hauser has the right link for the doc shared after the announcement that the webportal is unusable.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13112LHG9vVvNUs40oZSqZ-DF6_yFiT_SJZ2NaEmjMM4/edit#

Here are the lines from the doc I believe we are both referring you to...

1. Download the plutus-apps repository:

`git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps`

2. Go to the latest commit of the repository:

`git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd`

Be sure to do step 2 in your newly cloned repo dir. Then run the nix-shell. That will take a bit the first time.
A successful commit will result in something like this on your console...

```
~/plutus-apps$ git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd   
M       plutus-playground-client/package-lock.json
Note: switching to '7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 7f53f18df Bump hls to 1.5.1 #209 (#232)
```

I hope that is helpful!
If someone sees an error in my answer, please correct me...and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Google Doc link provided in the Pioneer Program announcement states `7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd`.

Comment: Which docs specify this commit?

Comment: The Google Doc from the announcement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13112LHG9vVvNUs40oZSqZ-DF6_yFiT_SJZ2NaEmjMM4/edit

Answer (score 0):

The document you mentioned: https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/MacOS.html is outdated as they have separated plutus-playground logic from plutus-core.

You can find plutus-playground related stuff in another repo:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps